How to efficiently copy 400,000 files between S3 buckets with different names and paths?
I have millions of files in an S3 bucket located in one AWS region. I need to copy about 400,000 of these files to another S3 bucket located in a different region, but with different file names and paths. I have a CSV file that maps the source keys to the destination keys, specifying where each file should be copied and what its new name should be.
Currently, I'm using the AWS CLI command aws s3 cp, but it's very slow and seems like it could take over a week to complete.
I've also experimented with S3 Batch Operations using a custom CSV manifest for a small test set of 5 files, but it appears that Batch Operations don't support renaming files or changing their paths during the copy process.
Given that the buckets are in different regions and the files need to be renamed and relocated during the copy, is there a more efficient way to handle this task? Any advice on tools, scripts, or AWS services that could help speed this up would be greatly appreciated.

Is this something you're going to do once, or will it be ongoing (ie, you'll have 10,000 files per week). If the latter, then I'd create something with SQS and Lambda, and let the Lambdas scale out to 20-ish concurrent executions.

If it's just once, then turn your listing into 400k discrete aws s3 cp commands, split that into 20 shell scripts, and run them concurrently. I'd probably spin up an EC2 instance so that I don't need to keep my laptop on, and use the screen command to open multiple sessions so that I can run the scripts in the foreground (and they won't be killed if I disconnect). 400k files / 20 scripts = 20k files each, or roughly 6 hours if each takes 1 second to copy.

@kdgregory this will be one time process.
I have ec2-instance where I have already started 40 shell scripts dividing all aws s3 cp commands and executed all scripts using below.
file_1.sh >> final_output.log 2>&1 &
file_2.sh >> final_output.log 2>&1 &
.
.
.
file_40.sh >> final_output.log 2>&1 &
it's been 18 hours but only 57,000 files are copied.
is there any better way to execute them?

Rather than using the AWS CLI, it would be faster to use an AWS SDK for your preferred programming language (eg boto3 for Python) and use multi-threading to execute many API calls concurrently. The program could read the CSV file and issues the API calls accordingly. It would use CopyObject(), which copies the object to another location. It does not "rename and relocate the data" -- it simply copies to a destination, with the original objects remaining unchanged.

@NiiL - that seems pathologically slow. How large are these files? If you're copying multiple gigabytes per file, then it might just take a long time. My other thought is that you're on a small burstable instance (tg, t3.nano) and have run out of CPU credits, Maybe also worth looking at top to see if you're IO bound, although you shouldn't be for a copy operation (since it just makes API calls and doesn't move any data through the program).

@JohnRotenstein - I question that advice. First, because it takes time to write code, especially multi-thread code. Second, because the AWS CLI is already written using boto3, so the only thing you save is startup time. Third, because Python isn't that great at multi-threading (and languages that are will take longer to code). And finally, because the numbers reported in the comment above indicate that something is not right.

@kdgregory instance is t2.medium

thanks @JohnRotenstein and kdgregory. I created python script and ran it from CloudShell and it is much much faster now.
